# Do periods of differential forms only depend on their cohomology class?

Tags: geometry, differential

The periods of a closed differential form are the values of the integration of the form along integral homology cycles. Is it correct that the periods depend only on the cohomology class i.e. do two closed forms in same cohomology class have same periods?

Comment: You might want to add the differential topology tag.

Comment: Please define "integral cycle."

Comment: Hint: Think about the Stokes theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In general, the integral of a differential form $\omega$ over a *closed* manifold (i.e. without boundary) only depends on the cohomology class of $\omega$. This follows immediately from Stokes' theorem: if $d\eta = \omega - \omega'$, then

$$\int_M \omega-\omega' = \int_M d\eta = \int_{\partial M} \eta = \int_\emptyset \eta = 0.$$

Since periods are integrals over closed cycles, they are really invariants of cohomology classes.

Comment: Just to add: You do not need $M$ to be a closed manifold, any smooth cycle (even over the reals) will suffice.

Comment: @studiosus  In case I wasn't clear: $M$ here is the cycle.